# PropertyGrid loose focus after RefreshProperties.All

Tags: c#, wpf, propertygrid, xceed

I am using WPF `Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.PropertyGrid` to show properties of my object for user to edit.

My class property is as shown below:

```
private double height;

[Browsable(true)]
[RefreshProperties(RefreshProperties.All)] 
public double Height
{
    get
    {
        return height;
    }

    set
    {            
        bodymass = height * 10;//Some other property
        _height= value;
    }
}
```

For each key press, set() is called and the grid row is loosing its focus due to `RefreshProperties.All`. Due to that, it is not possible to continuously type values to the grid row.

Is it possible to keep focus on the same property I was type in?

Or at least, it there a way to instruct the set() to be called only when user click enter/ loose focus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the `RefreshProperties` attribute, implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and raise the `PropertyChanged` event for all properties that you want to refresh in the setter of the `Height` property:

```
public class MyObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private double height;

    [Browsable(true)]
    public double Height
    {
        get
        {
            return height;
        }

        set
        {
            height = value;
            Test = height.ToString(); //this refreshes Test
        }
    }

    private string _test;
    public string Test
    {
        get { return _test; }
        set { _test = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

---

```
<xctk:PropertyGrid x:Name="_propertyGrid" Width="450" Margin="10" AutoGenerateProperties="False">
    <xctk:PropertyGrid.PropertyDefinitions>
        <xctk:PropertyDefinition TargetProperties="Height" />
        <xctk:PropertyDefinition TargetProperties="Test" />
    </xctk:PropertyGrid.PropertyDefinitions>
</xctk:PropertyGrid>
```

Comment: Thanks very much. But in this case I have to create so many backing variables for all other properties. Correct?

Comment: No, you could refresh any auto-implemented property by calling the NotifyPropertyChanged method and passing the name of the property that you want to update to it, e.g. NotifyPropertyChanged("TheNameOfThePropertyToUpdate");

Comment: You should also be able to refresh all data bound properties by passing an empty string or null to the NotifyPropertyChanged method.